# Azure devops release pipeline runs forever with error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm running a deployment on Azure pipelines and the release got stuck while copying files. This resulted in an unending process which is not desirable.

The error I received was:

> ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying File
>   C:\azagent\A2_work\r3\a_mach1-light\build\MyProject\HtmlRenderer.dll
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

I think this issue is not a permanent one since I've been able to successfully run the same release pipeline several times in the past but I want to figure out why it happens.

I've read several docs relating to Azure pipelines and troubleshooting on microsoft's website but none has been useful.

I've also tried to rerun the build pipeline so it could create another release but the issue still persists.

I'd be happy to get advice from anyone who has experienced this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try restarting the "Azure Pipelines Agent (MyCompanyName.MyMachineName)" service on the machine which hosts your deployment agent. See below screenshot.

[image]

For more Troubleshooting steps:

- Detect files and folders in use

> You can use tools like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to find out what process is using this specific file. See [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows).

- Anti-virus exclusion

> Anti-virus software scanning your files can cause file or folder in use errors during a build or release. Adding an anti-virus exclusion for your agent directory and configured "work folder" may help to identify anti-virus software as the interfering process.

If you use Msbuild in your pipeline:

- MSBuild and /nodeReuse:false
- MSBuild and /maxcpucount:[n]

Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#file-or-folder-in-use-errors) for more information above troubleshooting steps.

Comment: This is a very useful info but not the fix for my problem. Unfortunately, the DLL was actually being used by a running process. I figured the Winform desktop application using the HtmlRenderer.DLL file was not completely shut down so I force shut it down via Task manager and that solved my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Great to hear you fixed it. You can post the fix as the answer.

Comment: Why in the world is a single dll that was generated by a build process seemingly randomly being used by another process is what I'm wondering.